# How to check count from string

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have problem on Webservice,when Webservice return string data

```
if ([collectionView indexPathForCell:bookcell ].row == row) {
if ([[[bookList objectAtIndex:row] mainMenu] isEqualToString:@"standard"]) {

// [[bookList objectAtIndex:row] mainMenu]isEqualToString:@"standard"] have 5 row data 

}
}
```

I need to show `NSlog(@"count %d",total)`  how i can show total = 5 normally it's will show `count 1` 5 time but i need to show `count 5` 1 time Please Advice me.

Comment: I don't see a `total` variable in here.  Moreover, I don't know how you expect something with a value of `1` to log as `5`.  You are going to have to massively improve this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest thing is to count how many objects in your array "bookList" have word standard in it.

```
static int counter = 0; //make this a global variable

for (int i=0; i<[bookList count]; i++)
{

   NSString *str1 = [bookList objectAtIndex:i];
   if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"standard"])
   {
      counter++;
   }
}
```

now you got total count of word "standard" from your array